# Publish to Azure Error - Error : '', hexadecimal value 0x0F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 285

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to publish to Azure, but I am getting an error when the publish task occurs.

Transformed Web.config using C:\Users\Bootcamp\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ProjectAzure\ProjectAzure\Web.Debug.config into obj\Debug\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p "C:\Users\Bootcamp\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ProjectAzure\ProjectAzure\obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source" -u -c "C:\Users\Bootcamp\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ProjectAzure\ProjectAzure\obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir" 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.MSDeploy.Common.targets(55,5): Error : '', hexadecimal value 0x0F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 285.

Comment: how did this get resolved?

Answer (score 3):

Check your user data - e.g. I had a SQL Azure password that contained a % and the MSBuild/AzurePublisher threw a similar error. When I changed that then it worked